# HTML File is returned as weird character hodgepodge

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have the following code in my application:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
ob_clean();
@readfile($filename);
```

It is supposed to read an html file and writes in the response output.

The strange thing that happens now, is, that this works very well on one server, while on the other one it returns something that resembles an encoding error, like

`���&�lyY�]�����8���O��:���x��בw�6_an ����������+�G��͟>m��O�H&�WK�u>��_��(�U��z�_}�e�����ON�o��Y<�#�}��/�˵��}���Q��/ҼI?�Z1+�E��wZ�N묶��S�v�n_�o�B�9��e0��,�}=K[P�����������ڋ�����w���`.

This is definitely not due to an encoding issue of the respective file, because it happens as well when I replace

`@readfile($filename);`

with

`echo "ABCDE";`

Both are Linux Servers and the Apache and PHP Versions are pretty similar:

`PHP 5.6.35 / Apache/2.4.33` for the correct version,

`PHP 5.6.36 / Apache/2.4.18` for the incorrect one.

Comment: Is this an [mcve]? Does it happen with a PHP file containing just this code, or does the actual code actually do something else?

Comment: It is minimal, complete and verifiable, yes. And the code does nothing else but calculating the file name from some GET Parameters

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but I don't clearly understand why. Instead of `ob_clean()` it must be `ob_end_clean()`;